# Pairing ibeacons with iphone

Tags: iphone, ibeacon

I bought a Beacon device from gimbal and i activate it as a ibeacon. But now if i want the rssi signal from the ibeacon I have to pair to that beacon. But i don't know how to do that.

Can anyone help me to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you successfully put a Gimbal beacon into iBeacon mode, it behaves as a standard iBeacon.  This means that you do not have to do any pairing at all -- standard iBeacons do not even allow pairing.

To see the RSSI you need to do two things:

1. Find out the Proximity UUID of the iBeacon
2. Use the iOS CoreLocation APIs to range for beacons based on that Proximity UUID.  You can also use an off-the-shelf iOS app that does this like [Locate for iBeacon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-for-ibeacon/id738709014?mt=8), but you must first enter your UUID to such an app before the beacon will be visible on iOS.

Note that there are Android equivalents for step 2.  You would use the [Android iBeacon Library](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/) to range for the beacon, or the off-the-shelf [iBeacon Locate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.ibeaconlocate) app.